# VS 2015 project binding issue with SonarQube

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sonarqube, sonarlint-vs

I get below error when I try to bind to a SonarQube project within VS 2015.

Binding solution to SonarQube project: Download quality profile(s):
   Successfully downloaded quality profile. Name: 'Sonar way', Key: 'cs-sonar-way-33351', Language: 'C#'
SonarQube request failed: Sequence contains no elements 
Unexpected error during workflow execution: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..

Comment: Could you give a bit more context? Can you share the full log from the SonarLint output window? Is this issue specific to your solution or happens on all solutions on your machine? What's the version of your C# plugin in SQ?

Comment: I'm using SQ 6.0. Normally we get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." while we bind application to Sonar project. Can you please tell me what are the steps to bind project with Sonar projects.                                     1.

Comment: 2. Why I'm not able to load bugs reported by SQ from Sonar site to VS 2015 post successful binding. Also Bugs marked as Major, Critical etc on sonar site are shown as warning in VS 2015.

Comment: 3. Can I open SQ report for any project without opening application(for which report is generated) in VS 2015.

Comment: Please don't start new questions in comment. So 1: what's the c# plugin version on your SQ server? What other plugins do you have installed?

Comment: I have C# 5.3.2, latest one for SonarQube 6.0. I don't have other plugin installed. I had earlier PLSQL and Swift that I uninstalled. Could you please answer Question 2 & 3.

Comment: 2: SonarLint for Visual Studio Connected Mode doesn't yet support resolved issue hiding. It will come in a future release. 3: I don't fully understand this. Yes you can check the analysis result on your SonarQube server.

Comment: Rewriting question #2. I ran analysis using sonar-scanner. Results are available on sonar site. This result I want to load inside visual studio after my VS project binding with Sonar project is successful. What I found is you need to open each and every file in the solution files to get error-list window populated with results. Also can you please tell me, Is it possible to run analysis from VS 2015 itself or it just loads result from sonar site.

Comment: This is a VS feature to reduce memory and CPU usage. Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt709421.aspx